# Usage of __attribute__((section)) for variable placement

Tags: c, pragma, sections

I am using arm compiler 6 and I have a use case where I need to place a number of variables under one particular section.

For a single variable , it works fine .
Like :

```
int var __attribute__((mysec))
```

In my scatter (linker) file, var variable appears correctly in the address pointed by “mysec” section.

Now, I have a usecase where I need to store `var`, `var1` and `var2` in the  same section - “mysec”.

I also want to avoid using `__attribute__((mysec))` for each variable.

I found something related to pragma that could help here , but nothing worked out .

Can you let me know if there is any way possible for this?

Comment: Other than maybe complicated stuff with linker scripts, I don't think this is possible, except for the obvious `int __attribute__((section("mysec"))) var, var1, var2;`.  Most people handle this just by creating a macro for `__attribute__((section("mysec")))` to save typing.

Comment: You can instruct the linker (with your scatter file) to put the objects from specific `*.o` files into specified sections if it helps.

Comment: Perhaps `objcopy` might be helpful, renaming sections of an object file. Just to mention another alternative.